# Full blown MvvmCross example - the latest

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Does anyone knows of latest full-blown example of mvvmcross from the latest time?

(maybe with support for Xamarin Forms) with as much plugins etc, to learn from?

(i know the CollectABull of Stuart, but it's from 2 years ago..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New samples for Android support and Xamarin Forms have been released recently: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/tree/master/Samples

If you have any specific questions about MvvmCross implementations, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks  @Martijn00 ! it's great.
I'll look on it.
But i search something bigger , a full app with all aspects of mvvmcross (like CollectABull , but i assume more modern (is any?) )

those samples are small ones (aren't they?) for pointing how to engage XF.
i'm looking for reference app to download and learn from the code.
(i already watched the whole N+1 sessions, so i need now only code)
Thanks very much!

Comment: You can't expect us to make your app, so you need to develop it yourself. If you need any help on specific part, or need explanation in certain areas i would be happy to help!

Comment: i don't expect you to make my app.
i think it's better and easyier  to learn from all aspects of mvvmcross on a single app . like the prebuilt apps of xamarin , like CollectAbull (is CollectABull is updated to the latest bits and patterns?)
Am I wrong?

Comment: @Martijn00, cannot able to access to the repo.